# How do i create the array with the values being fetched from database in php

Tags: php

Say i am having set of rows in a table and each row is having a column called city  with  some values assigned to it 
  iam iterating through the result set  and  i need to assign the list of city values of each row  in to an array only unique

```
     foreach($res as $row){
       $cities =array();
       $cities[] = $row['city'];
       //when i say 
       var_dump($cities);
       //Iam not able to get array .how do i do that 
       $maincities = array('A','B',C)
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're resetting `$cities` to a new array for each row you loop through. Better would be:

```
$cities = array();
foreach ($res as $row)
{
    if ( ! in_array($row['city'], $cities)) {
        $cities[] = $row['city'];
    }
}
```

Comment: iam getting null array when i try to compare the cities array  with main city array 


if (  !in_array($row['city'], $mainarray)) {
    echo "one";     
          $cities[] = $row['city'];
     }
 var_dump($cities)

Comment: @some: Why do you use `$mainarray` when the answer states `$cities`? Sound more like mixing up variables (especially the NULL part...)

Comment: @Someone - you'll need to post up your full code if you want any more help. We're not here to guess! My answer will work when used correctly! What is `$maincities` compared to `$cities`?

Answer (score 2):

You should but `$cities =array();`before the foreach loop. Now you are erasing the array at each iteration.

Regards,
Alin

Answer (score 2):

1. You empty the `$cities` variable every time in the loop.
2. It is probably a lot better practise to only *have* unique cities in your resultset (`SELECT DISTINCT city FROM ...`)

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
$cities =array();
foreach($res as $row){      
   $cities[] = $row['city'];       
}
var_dump($cities);
```

However it depends on the content of `$res`

Answer (score 1):

Using keys to eliminate duplicates:

```
$cities = array();
foreach($res as $row)
  $cities[$row['city']] = true;
$cities = array_keys($cities);
```

Comment: I agree. But some times you may need the non-distinct data as well, and you'd have to run a second query to get the distinct values. Example: If building a faceted search, you might want to display all of the results, along with a checkbox for each distinct city, category, etc, found within that resultset.